# Do we have Analytical function like RANK/LAG in Spark Structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I would like to use an Analytical function like RANK/LAG in Spark Structured streaming.

1. Do we have Analytical Window function in Spark Structured Streaming by any chance?I am aware `org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window` is available, but this probably works with Data Frames only, not with Spark Structured streaming. Also, `org.apache.spark.sql.window` method is purely used for sliding data in window in Structured streaming.
2. Also, Any suggestions on how to pick Max Date record in a group, in Spark structured streaming if we don’t have rank option.

   ```
   val groupedOutput = joinedDf.groupBy(
       window(col("timestampIpfr"), "2 minutes"),
       col("userid"), col("timestampIpfr")
     ).agg(max("timestampMME").alias("maxTimestampMME"),
       max("locationMME").alias("locationMME")

   //Max on locationMME doesn't work here, looking for help on the same to find locationMME of maxTimestampMME record
   )
   ```

Expecting Grouped output value with max timestampMME record and corresponding locationMME

Comment: _"Max on locationMME doesn't work here"_ because it should use `maxTimestampMME` instead.

Comment: _"but this probably works with Data Frames only, not with Spark Structured streaming"_ is correct

Comment: Have a look to this similar topic (including the solution)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72646180/pyspark-structured-streaming-with-window-get-earliest-latest-record-based-upon